# F/MiTeeESE-HAL(13055): Error while registering secure_element V1.2 service: -2147483648

Tags: service, secure-element, registering

I'm new to flutter and whole android development. When I run the virtual device from Android Studio, I don't get any errors, but when I connect my device to my laptop (with USB debugging enabled and google USB drivers installed from AS), I keep getting these errors . While I can run the default Flutter app on my android device, for now, I fear it will cause me more headaches in the future and be annoying

F/MiTeeESE-HAL(13258): Error while registering secure_element V1.2 service: -2147483648
F/MiTeeESE-HAL(13292): Error while registering secure_element V1.2 service: -2147483648
F/MiTeeESE-HAL(13318): Error while registering secure_element V1.2 service: -2147483648
F/MiTeeESE-HAL(13344): Error while registering secure_element V1.2 service: -2147483648
F/MiTeeESE-HAL(13370): Error while registering secure_element V1.2 service: -2147483648
F/MiTeeESE-HAL(13391): Error while registering secure_element V1.2 service: -2147483648
F/MiTeeESE-HAL(13425): Error while registering secure_element V1.2 service: -2147483648
F/MiTeeESE-HAL(13452): Error while registering secure_element V1.2 service: -2147483648

The above error keeps repeating.